# Separate icons for Chrome and Hangouts in Unity

Tags: 14.04, unity, google-chrome, google-hangouts

Is there a way to have separate icons for Chrome and Hangouts in Unity? All my Chrome windows and Hangouts chats are combined under the Chrome icon.

I swear I've seen them separate before, but I can't figure out how to get that behavior again.

Comment: I've tried it many times, but I think there is no solutions at this moment. I have got a simular question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/534199/different-icons-for-multiple-profiles-in-chrome-apps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open a terminal and edit the following files:

```
gedit $HOME/.local/share/applications/chrome-*&
```

Find the file corresponding to Hangouts and inside the file remove the following entry:

```
NoDisplay=true
```

Typically, the Hangouts file will have the following entry that you can use to identify it.

```
Name=Hangouts
```

You can also enable the rest of google applications like google drive, docs etc that are disabled by default. I hope it helps.

The contents of my Hangout file are listed below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Name=Hangouts
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --profile-directory=Default --app-id=knipolnnllmklapflnccelgolnpehhpl
Icon=chrome-knipolnnllmklapflnccelgolnpehhpl-Default
StartupWMClass=crx_knipolnnllmklapflnccelgolnpehhpl
```

The file name and location is

```
$HOME/.local/share/applications/chrome-knipolnnllmklapflnccelgolnpehhpl-Default.desktop
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I don't seem to have an entry for Hangouts (I only see Hangouts call, and it has no `NoDisplay=true` in it)

Comment: The chrome menu files are automatically generated. If you delete the files and restart chrome they will be re-generated. I can post my Hangout settings if you want too.

Comment: Please do, just in case. I will try  removing the files and killing chrome.

Comment: I modified my answer above to include this info now.