# Separate icons for Chromium and Hangouts in Unity (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: unity, launcher, icons, chromium, google-hangouts

I installed the [Hangouts extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-hangouts/nckgahadagoaajjgafhacjanaoiihapd?hl=ca), but both hangouts and Chromium share the same entry in the Unity launcher, which makes it very difficult to switch between Chromium windows and chat windows (see image below)

[image]

Alse, when ALT-tabbing, window thumbnails are not very helpful:

[image]

Is there any way to isolate the Hangouts extension icon from the Chromium windows icon in Unity launcher?

Note: There's a [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528913/separate-icons-for-chrome-and-hangouts-in-unity) in Ask Ubuntu, but the accepted answer doesn't apply here (the config file is not present).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the extension (not the separate app), you can add the icon by yourself.
So in terminal copy this command:

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/chrome-hangouts.desktop
```

And now paste this code and change the values with whatever your extension id is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Name=Hangouts
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --profile-directory=Default --app-id=*extension_id*
Icon=*use_your_icon_path_here*
StartupWMClass=crx_*extension_id*
```

You can find your extension id by going to Tools>Extensions and from 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEDeD.png).
And this is the [end result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBMCq.png).

**Edit:**
The guide was for Chrome (since that's the one I use on my machine). For chromium I guess you just need to change the `Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome` into `Exec=/usr/bin/chromium-browser --profile-directory=Default --app-id=*extension_id*`
 for chromium (use another .desktop entry from the same path).
And the extension id is usually the same, but sometimes they update it and change it, the reason why just copy/pasting earlier answers wouldn't work.